# RewriteRule redirects to domain root

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make any image file name that doesn't exists in my server to load default.jpg in it.

This is what I tried on my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\w+\.jpg$ /default.jpg
```

But everytime I access my /randomimagename.jpg the browser redirects me to my domain root.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your file? I ask because you haven't used a LAST flat `[L]` it will continue to process the other rules, so if any catch your `/default.jpg` and rewrite it, you'll get unexpected behaviour.

Comment: This is the only rule!

Comment: The trusty .htaccess tester says it should work... http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=16091bd0-fc0e-5d01-8a54-76422c765d0e - I know this is a silly question... but is `/default.jpg` there if you browse directly to it?

Comment: "...the browser redirects me to my domain root." - You see an external 3xx redirect? If so, then something else is triggering that. Have you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: Actually if I try to open /default.jpg it also redirects me to the domain root, but the file is in the folder. Maybe I should add an exception on the htaccess file to ignore "default.jpg" to be affected by the RewriteRule? Also it's not an external 3xx redirect!

Comment: Tried everything, the htaccess tester tells me it's everything alright but the same problem still persists. http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=df8342cd-9087-5b48-a1a7-2f4b3f489d96

Comment: Do you have a other htaccess file in any other directory? Or did you had one before?

Comment: Yes I do, the directory hierarchy is: /var/www/html/img/3432/ and I have one .htacces file in html and another one in 3432 which is the directory I'm working right now with this problem.

Comment: If this `.htaccess` file is located at `/img/3432/.htaccess` (assuming `/var/www/html` is your document root), then where is `default.jpg` located? And what image URL are you requesting? The directive you posted unconditionally rewrites all images - not just those that don't exist? Is that intentional? Are there no images in this subdirectory?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.jpg$ /default.jpg [NC,L]
```

Comment: Minor point... the additional check that it's _not a directory_ would seem to be redundant (unless you also have directories that end in `.jpg`!).